# How to add common path in spring controller when view page is searched?

Tags: spring, tiles

I'm trying to develop a spring mvc application. This is part of my controller class.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("account")
public class Account 
{
    @RequestMapping(value="register", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String register()
    {
        return "account/register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login()
    {
        return "account/login";
    }
}
```

And this is part of my tiles definition

```
<definition name="*/*" extends="base">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/{1}/{2}.jsp" />
</definition>
```

I don't like to add "account/" prefix before every return in controller. Is there any way to add "account/" before "register" or "login" without writing explicitly each time?